Не удаётся загрузить библиотеку stplanr
Не удаётся загрузить и работать с  библиотекой stplanr. при попытке запустить код вылезает следующее:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stplanr’ in
dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/curl/libs/curl.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/curl/libs/curl.so,
0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace (_curl_url_strerror)

Подскажите, как это можно исправить. Библиотеку загружала и через tools, и через install.packages
